# Greatest value of (cot(A/2)+cot(B/2)+cot(C/2))/(cotA+cotB+cotC) in triangleABC

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

[image]

I am  struck at the last step. Please help me to proceed further.

Comment: Please do not include vital parts of your question as an image.  All of that work should be typed out using MathJax.

Comment: Why this question was put on hold? I have shown my thoughts in this question, haven't I?

Comment: As I said yesterday, please do not put vital information into an image.  Type out the mathematics using MathJax.  There is a tutorial on the [Meta site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cauchy-Schwarz, or just $(a-b)^2\ge0$, implies
$$ a^2+b^2\ge 2ab,$$
and so on for $b,c$ and $c,a$. Add them all up we got
$$2(a^2+b^2+c^2) \ge 2(ab+bc+ca),$$
which means
$$ \frac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\le 1.$$
That would solve your last step.

And Xander was right, try to post in LaTeX markup.